# Here's the code for arranging given numbers in ascending order . But when I submit it in Codechef it gives runtime(SIGSEGV) error?

Tags: c

thanks in advance for the help .....
thought this was my first post on stackoverflow . but i must say it took me like 10 minutes to just pass all the errors and stuffs.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int a[1000000];

int main()
{
    long int i,temp,n,j,k;
    scanf("%ld",&n);
    k=n-1;
    //takes the input and stores in the array
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        scanf ("%ld",&a[i]);
    }
    //swaps the element
    for(j=n-1;j>=n-k;j--){
        for(i=0;i<n-1;i++){
            if(a[i]>a[i+1]){
                temp=a[i];
                a[i]=a[i+1];
                a[i+1]=temp;
            }
        }
    }
    //prints the swapped elements
    for(i=0;i<n;i++) {
        printf("%ld\n",a[i]);
    }
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: what if I enter 100 the very first time?

Comment: `"it took me like 10 minutes to just pass all the errors and stuffs"` - What does this even mean?  Errors in your code?  What are they?

Comment: link to the question https://www.codechef.com/problems/TSORT

Comment: it's nothing it's not related to code

Comment: . you can't enter 100 since it can only take values upto 20.

Comment: @David He is probably referring to the fact that stackoverflow kept throwing errors (i.e. "too much code, not enough words") and is lamenting that he had to burn 10 minutes of his precious time getting his question up to minimum standards.

Comment: It looks to me like when the variable i = 19 in your loops, then you will be trying to access a[20] which is an array out of bounds error.

Comment: They give only 50000 bytes per program and if i go by their rules of 10^6 then i have to replace 20 with 10^6 which will be more than 50000.

Comment: @bruceg No, when you will keep 19 then the condition will get wrong and the loop will terminate. so i don't think outofbounds is a problem??

Comment: @user5910213 That's not what that means.  It means the size of your .c file can be a maximum of 50000 bytes in size, not that you can't use numbers larger than that in your program.

Comment: I did that buddy but it's still showing the same error.. And i thank you all guys for taking your time to resolving this doubt..

Comment: Guys please help if you could I am stuck really bad it is working on my pc fine but in codechef the same runtime error pops up

Answer (score 0):

the problem states that there can be up to 10^6 (1000000) entries.

Your code is only allowing for 20 entries.
The code seems to work for small numbers of numbers.

Suggest just change `a[20]` to `a[1000000]`

Comment: It further gives time limit exceeded

Answer (score 0):

the main problem with the latest posted code from the OP is the sorting algorithm.

`bubble`, `insertion` and similar sorting algorithms take massive amounts of time when the number of entries gets beyond ~10 due to the number of comparisons that need to be made.

The following code meets the criteria about the number of entries and the range of valid values for each entry

It uses the `qsort` function as that is orders of magnitude faster than a bubble or insertion sort when the number of numbers gets large

the following code does not print duplicate numbers, (the codechef problem indicates (but does not specifically say) that duplicate numbers are to only be printed once.

caveat: if the count of number of numbers (the first thing read) is <=0 then this code fails.

caveat: if all the data numbers are INT_MAX then this code fails.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h>

size_t values[1000000];


int cmpfunc (const void * a, const void * b)
{
   return (int)( *(size_t*)a - *(size_t*)b );
}


int main(void)
{
    size_t i;
    size_t numberCount; // number of numbers

    // get count of numbers
    scanf("%lu",&numberCount);


    //takes the input and stores in the array
    for( i=0; i<numberCount; i++)
    {
        scanf ("%lu",&values[i]);
    }

    qsort(values, numberCount, sizeof(size_t), cmpfunc);

    //print only the unique sorted elements
    size_t oldValue = INT_MAX;
    for( i=0; i<numberCount; i++ )
    {
        if( oldValue != values[i] )
        {
            printf("%ld\n", values[i]);
            oldValue = values[i];
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried this code with several modest sized sets of data, but have not submitted it to codechef.

**EDIT:**

The following code is MUCH faster and sorts the numbers as they are input.  and works with all the corner cases I was able to come up with.

Corner cases like a 't' value of 0, 1 and values of 0 through 1000000 (10^6)

```
/*
 * criteria 1
 * Given the list of numbers, you are to sort them in non decreasing order.
 *
 * critiera 2
 * t – the number of numbers in list, then t lines follow [t <= 10^6].
 *
 * criteria 3
 * Each line contains one integer: N [0 <= N <= 10^6]
 *
 * implied criteria 4
 * duplicate input numbers are to be output only once
 */


#include <stdio.h>


#define MAX_VALUE (1000000)

int array[ MAX_VALUE +1 ];

int main( void )
{
    // get number of test cases
    size_t  numInputs;
    scanf( "%lu", &numInputs );

    // accumulate test cases, sorted
    for( size_t i=0; i<numInputs; i++ )
    {
        int value;
        scanf( "%d", &value );
        array[value]++;
    }

    // output the unique values, assending
    for( size_t i=0; i<MAX_VALUE; i++ )
    {
        if( array[i] )
        {
            printf( "%d\n", array[i] );
        }
    }


    return 0;
}
```

All the accepted submissions are available for this codechef exercise.

Strongly suggest looking at the presented solutions for 'C'

Then use the methods for reading/writing a integer value, because it is much faster than using `scanf()` and `printf()` and does not have any possibility of failing like `scanf()` does.

(I also noticed that many of the accepted solutions look like one submission got accepted, then everyone else copied that solution, even across languages, the same variable names, etc are used.

If you incorporate the method of reading/writing an integer as shown in the accepted solutions, it may help with getting your own solution to be accepted.  Strongly suggest, do not copy the 'guts' of their code for the solution,  But I have seen the same method of reading/writing integers used on several of the different problem sets.

**EDIT2**

here are the fast read and write functions that I mentioned above:

They replace the calls to `scanf()` and `printf()`

```
#include <stdio.h>

void fastRead( size_t *a );
void fastWrite( size_t a );

inline void fastRead(size_t *a)
{
    int c=0;
    // note: 32 is space character
    while (c<33) c=getchar_unlocked();

    // initialize result value
    *a=0;

    // punctuation parens, etc are show stoppers
    while (c>47 && c<58)
    {
        *a = (*a)*10 + (size_t)(c-48);
        c=getchar_unlocked();
    }
    //printf( "%s, value: %lu\n", __func__, *a );
} // end function: fastRead


inline void fastWrite(size_t a)
{
    char snum[20];
    //printf( "%s, %lu\n", __func__, a );

    int i=0;
    do
    {
        // 48 is numeric character 0
        snum[i++] = (char)((a%10)+(size_t)48);
        a=a/10;
    }while(a>0);

    i=i-1; // correction for overincrement from prior 'while' loop

    while(i>=0)
    {
        putchar_unlocked(snum[i--]);
    }
    putchar_unlocked('\n');
} // end function: fastWrite
```

Comment: I have noticed that codechef often lists some answer as wrong (sadly codechef never says what was wrong about the answer, so, effectively, there is no feedback.)  However, the code does do what the criteria in the question requires.  It is up to you to 'guess' what the difference between what codechef wants and what the answer code outputs.

Comment: the first EDIT shows how to eliminate any sorting time taken during execution.  the second EDIT2 shows a much faster way to read and write integers,   I have no idea why CodeChef is saying it gives the wrong answer

Answer (score 0):

Guys one of the answers regarding this is not to use Bubble sort. Because it can't handle large data. And i have used bubble sort. The problem can only be sorted by Merge Sort. This works fine even for large datas.